# Looping in ArrayLists with a Method

Tags: java, methods, multidimensional-array, arraylist, anagram

With much assistance I have developed a method that makes anagrams and then adds them into an `ArrayList`.

```
public void f(String s, String anagram, ArrayList<String> array)
{
    if(s.length() == 0)
    {
        array.add(anagram);
        return;
    }
    for(int i = 0 ; i < s.length() ; i++)
    {
        char l = s.charAt(i);
        anagram = anagram + l;
        s = s.substring(0, i) + s.substring(i+l, s.length());
        f(s,anagram,array);
    }
}
```

The problem is when I attempt to use this function to make `ArrayList`s in a loop that adds `String`s from one `ArrayList` to another, I get an error saying I can't use a void, and the method `f()` is void.

```
        List<String> Lists = new ArrayList<String>(); //makes new array list
        for(String List : words)
        { //takes values from old array list
            List.trim();
            Lists.add(f(List,"",new ArrayList<String>())); //this is where it doesn't work
        }
```

Let me clarify once more:
I want to use this function to insert `ArrayList`s of anagrams into each position in another `ArrayList`. The anagram Lists are derived from `String`s that are being read from one list to another. I tried changing the method to static but that doesn't work, I also removed the `return;` in the method once, but that doesn't fix it either.

How do I make this whole thing work?

Comment: Where is `words` defined from?

Comment: `List` is a terrible variable name, as it shadows the type name.  Replace your for loop with `for (String word : words)` for clarity, then take the advice below.

Comment: The word `words` is the name of the `ArrayList` being read. 

I changed the `List` to `fList` and the `ArrayList` name to `fLists`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error happens because the method `f()` is `void`, meaning: it doesn't return any value that can be added to the `ArrayList`.

The answer of invoking `f()` is stored in the `ArrayList` passed as a parameter to `f`, you should probably use *that* `ArrayList` to add all of its elements to `Lists`. Something like this:

```
List<String> lists = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String list : words) {
    list.trim();
    ArrayList<String> answer = new ArrayList<String>();
    f(list, "", answer);
    lists.addAll(answer);
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but would passing `new ArrayList<String>()` as a function parameter not be a "pass by value" and not "pass by reference"? The function `f()` would be called with a blank list that is never affected in the parent function

Comment: In Java, all parameters are passed by value, but the value of an Object is an object reference, so changes to the ArrayList will be externally visible.

Comment: @TheCapn In Java all parameters are passed by value, there is no pass-by-reference semantics in the language. And yes, the list _will_ be modified inside the method an will contain all the values after the method returns, because both the arraylist reference _inside_ the method and the one _outside_ the method are pointing to exactly the same object

Comment: Not to sound lazy or unintelligent, but could you show me or at least give me a visual of some sorts? I'm a java noob.

Comment: I'm really not sure how to implement what you're telling me, but everyone thinks it's great advice. I just need more detail. I'm new to java so what to do where is a bit confusing if I can't see what it looks like or close too.

Comment: Without altering my method I added the new `ArrayList` after the `.trim()`, I had tried this before with the new `ArrayList` before the `.trim()`. It did not work then either. I am still getting a error pertaining to the use of a non-static method. It says "non-static method f() cannot be referenced from a static method"

Comment: Then by all means, make `f` static: `public static void f`

Comment: I preformed a large `facepalm` for that one. Thank you for your patience and help `Óscar López` :)

Comment: @RyanTibbetts ouch, that looks like a problem with the `i` index when calling `substring` in `f()`. Isolate the input that caused the problem and then fiddle around with the index until it works. If necessary post a new question with your findings

Comment: @ÓscarLópez No need for a new thread. It was a simple mistake. If you look at the code where the `substring`s are and look at the second`substring`, you'll notice it says `i+l` which is supposed to be `i+1` but `l` and `1` look so alike that I didn't even notice XD only problem now is the anagram is not moving the first letter in the array so I gotta fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Your method header for F needs to look like this:

```
public String f(String s, String anagram, ArrayList<String> array)
```

And then you return a String value to add to that ArrayList you are using.

Comment: This won't work because `f` might need to return more than one string.

Comment: Guess you could just do String[] then

Answer (score 0):

Your function definition for `f()` shows the return value of type `void`. So looking at your code you're attempting to do this:

```
Lists.add(void);
```

which is obviously illegal.

Your choice really is to have the ArrayList declared in a greater scope.

```
private List<String> anagrams;

public void f(String s, String anagram) {
  ...
  anagrams.add(anagram);
  ...
}

....

 for(String List : words) {
   //takes values from old array list
   anagrams = new ArrayList<String>();
   List.trim();
   f(list,"");
   Lists.add(anagrams); //this is where it doesn't work
 }
```

Comment: I cannot do this because it would constantly alter the List anagrams because it is not static. I need to make multiple Lists.